# Google Cloud Data Transfer Tool Only Ever Succeeds To Retrieve ~95% of Files

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use the [Data Transfer](https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer/cloud) tool in Google Cloud to make daily backups of my Firebase Cloud Storage database into Google Cloud Storage. However whenever I make a run, I get `NOT_FOUND` errors with the message `Failed to read metadata for source object.` for about 95%-98% of my objects.

If I try to re-run the Data Transfer tool, I'll get another 95%-98% success rate, but on different objects.

Nowhere in the documentation for the Data Transfer tool are either of these error messages described - in addition there isn't much logging to view, so I don't even know how to start debugging this.

I tried creating a second Storage Bucket with higher specs (better availability/region) to see if that would help, but it was the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation of Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/known-limitations-transfer#changed-objects). The error message "Failed to read object metadata" when doing Data Transfer happens when the object your are attempting to transfer is being modified. Changing the object/file means having changes in the object's metadata as well, causing a mismatch.

In order to resolve this situation it would be necessary for the objects to remain unchanged during the transfer process. To that extent you may stop whatever logic updates them or [place object locks in the objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/holding-objects#use-object-holds).

Comment: I'm getting a "NOT_FOUND" error, but the link you provided refers to "FILE_MODIFIED_FAILURE" or "PRECONDITION_FAILURE". It also doesn't say anything about "Failed to read object metadata"

Comment: @Dr-Bracket those errors you've mentioned are for on-prem to Google Cloud and vice versa. Have you tried to do the data transfer again applying the recommendations I provided? Please make sure that the objects are not being modified while doing the transfer.

Comment: The transfer I'm doing is between Firebase Storage Bucket and a new bucket I made on Google Cloud Storage- So it's not on prem. The data is also not getting changed at that frequency and it's a different error message than the one you describe

Comment: @Dr-Bracket if you are certain that objects are not being modified during the transfer process, I suggest you open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for someone to monitor the transfer process closely.